# Keep getting this error : Invalid query: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql

This is my script to create the database. Thanks in advance for the help everybody .

The four tables I am inserting data into when the error occurs are :

1. asset
2. asset_details
3. location
4. invoice

---

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `inventory1` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `inventory1` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`department`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`department` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`department` (
  `department_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `department_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `job_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`department_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`employee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`employee` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`employee` (
  `employee_id` INT NULL ,
  `department_id` INT NULL ,
  `fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone_number` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `hire_date` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `job_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `manager_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`) ,
  INDEX `department_id` (`department_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `department_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`department_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`department` (`department_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`invoice`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`invoice` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`invoice` (
  `invoice_number` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
  `invoice_date` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `purchase_price` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `quantity` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `order_date` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `vender` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `warranty_end` DATE NULL ,
  `notes` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `vender_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_number`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`assignment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`assignment` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`assignment` (
  `assignment_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `assignment_status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`assignment_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`asset`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`asset` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`asset` (
  `asset_tag` INT NOT NULL ,
  `cap_ex` VARCHAR(10) NULL ,
  `asset_type_id` INT NULL ,
  `invoice_number` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
  `status_id` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asset_tag`) ,
  INDEX `assignment_id` (`status_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `invoice_number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`invoice_number` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`invoice` (`invoice_number` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `assignment_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`status_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`assignment` (`assignment_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`location`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`location` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`location` (
  `location_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `location_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `rack` INT NULL ,
  `row` INT NULL ,
  `unit` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`physical_asset`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`physical_asset` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`physical_asset` (
  `physical_asset_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `location_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `employee_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `physical_asset_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`physical_asset_id`) ,
  INDEX `location_id` (`location_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `employee_id` (`employee_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `location_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`location` (`location_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `employee_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`employee` (`employee_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`asset_details`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`asset_details` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`asset_details` (
  `asset_type_id` INT NULL ,
  `asset-tag` INT NULL ,
  `asset_type` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `physical_asset_id` INT NULL ,
  `manufacturer` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `os` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `os_version` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `make` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `model` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `serial_number` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `processor` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `ram` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `memory` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `hdd` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `host_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `notes` VARCHAR(250) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asset_type_id`) ,
  INDEX `physical_asset_id` (`physical_asset_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `asset_tag` (`asset-tag` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `physical_asset_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`physical_asset_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`physical_asset` (`physical_asset_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `asset_tag`
    FOREIGN KEY (`asset-tag` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`asset` (`asset_tag` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Welcome! That's wild. Please *format* your code on SO by editing and selecting and clicking the `{}` for each statement (not everything!).

Comment: Stop inserting records with a key that already exists.

Comment: add auto-increment flag for primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to be sure that you use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on your primary keys, otherwise it will try to make them all 0, which it can't because primary keys have to be unique.

Comment: Okay thank you. But my problem is that I need the asset tag to be entered by the user and not auto incremented . How would I go around this problem ?

Comment: Your primary key always needs to be an `AUTO_INCREMENT` integer, thus the asset tag should not be the primary key. Most of the time your primary key is going to be an "id" column, although it doesn't have to be called "id". If you have another column that needs indexed, you can set an index on it without making it primary.